# C# add Quick Table (Building Block) in Word

Tags: c#, ms-word, vsto, office-interop, word-automation

I created a Quick Table as a table template in my template dotx. I would like to create a Quick Table programmatically. is that possible?

Currently I use an existing table as template and copy its properties to the new table (see code).

```
object oTemplate = "D:\\Templates\\tables.dotx";
Word._Document doc = word.Documents.Add(oTemplate, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing);

// Copy first table as template
Word.Table tableTemplate = doc.Tables[1];
Word.Range rangeCopy = tableTemplate.Range;
rangeCopy.Copy();


...


// Reuse table template for new tables

object oMissing = Missing.Value;
var newTable = doc.Tables.Add(range, 1, 1, ref oMissing, ref oMissing);
newTable.Range.Paste();
```

The problem is that the dummy table is not deleted by the pasting, but moved downwards.

**Solution**:

1. Create a Building Block in the template file (tables.dotx in my case)
2. Load the Building Block in C#
3. Insert into range

`var template = (Word.Template)doc.get_AttachedTemplate();`

`Word.BuildingBlock objBB = template.BuildingBlockEntries.Item("MyCustomBlock");`

`objBB.Insert(range, true);`

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "Quick Table"? Could you maybe give the UI commands used, or a screen shot or something? FWIW I get the impression that what you need is a **Building Block** stored in the template that can be inserted on-demand...

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Quick Table is: Insert > Table > Drop Down > Quick Table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "Quick Tables" in the `Insert > Table > Drop Down > Quick Table` list are Building Blocks. They can also be found in `Insert > Text > Quick Parts > Building Block Organizer`, in the Tables gallery. This means these tables are stored in the user profile's Building Blocks template and should be part of a standard installation.

The basic (VBA) code to insert a built-in (installed as part of Office) Building Block is:

```
    Application.Templates( _
    "C:\Users\[user name]\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Document Building Blocks\1033\14\Built-In Building Blocks.dotx" _
    ).BuildingBlockEntries("Calendar 2").Insert Where:=Selection.Range, _
    RichText:=True
```

And for C#

```
Word.Template objTmpl = wdApp.Templates[@"C:\Users\[user name]\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Document Building Blocks\1033\14\Built-In Building Blocks.dotx"];
Word.BuildingBlock objBB = objTmpl.BuildingBlockEntries.Item("Calendar 2");
objBB.Insert(rng, true);
```

If it's uncertain that this template will have been installed, or installed to a specific file path, then the more certain approach would be to save the table as a Building Block in the template being distributed as part of VSTO solution. That's simply a matter of selecting the table then using `Insert > Text > Quick Parts > Save selection to Quick Part Gallery`. In the dialog box be sure to select the template from the `Save in` list as the default could well be the installation template with the building blocks.

To insert a Building Block in the template from which a document was created (the "attached template"):

```
Word.Template objTmpl = (Word.Template)doc.get_AttachedTemplate();
```

Comment: thank you very much for the detailed answer. i think this is going in the right direction. the building block is stored in my regular template (tables.dotx). if i query the file via word.templates[".../tables.dotx"] i get an error message that it is not in the collection. the same error appears with the standard building block dotx template. do i have to add it somehow?

Comment: If it's not in the collection it's probably not loaded in memory. A template will only be in the `Templates` collection if it is 1) loaded as an Add-in or 2) attached to an open document (and then only in relation to that specific document). Without understanding more context, it's difficult for me to say what the problem might be, beyond that...

Comment: I found an earlier solution from you, also working :) :

var template = (Word.Template)doc.get_AttachedTemplate();
Word.BuildingBlock objBB = template.BuildingBlockEntries.Item("MyCustomBlock");
objBB.Insert(range, true);